# Maximum Contiguous Subsequence Sum of At Least Length L (recursive)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

```
int maxSumRec( const vector<int> & a, int left, int right )
{
    if( left == right )  // Base case
        return a[ left ];

    int center = ( left + right ) / 2;
    int maxLeftSum  = maxSumRec( a, left, center );
    int maxRightSum = maxSumRec( a, center + 1, right );

    int maxLeftBorderSum = 0, leftBorderSum = 0;
    for( int i = center; i >= left; i-- )
    {
        leftBorderSum += a[ i ];
        if( leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum )
            maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum;
    }

    int maxRightBorderSum = 0, rightBorderSum = 0;
    for( int j = center + 1; j <= right; j++ )
    {
        rightBorderSum += a[ j ];
        if( rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum )
            maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum;
    }

    return max3( maxLeftSum, maxRightSum,
                maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum );
}
```

This function will return the Maximum Contiguous Subsequence of the vector.  The task is to implement a minimum sequence parameter called "L" that then returns the maximum contiguous subsequence of at least length L.

Example: without L parameter:

```
vector<int> a(4);
a[ 0 ] = 1; a[ 1 ] = 3; a[ 2 ] = -20; a[ 3 ] = 7;
maxSumRec(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
```

would return "7"

Example: with L parameter:

```
int L = 3;
vector<int> a(4);
a[ 0 ] = 1; a[ 1 ] = 3; a[ 2 ] = -20; a[ 3 ] = 7;
maxSumRec(a, 0, a.size() - 1, L);
```

would return "-9"

I know this can be easily done with other different max sum functions but the task is explicitly for this recursive formula.  I do not know how to even start. The professor gave us this hint to work with: "The major difficulty caused by adding minSeq to the recursive algorithm is in the border sum calculations.
Clearly, we can assume that each of the two border sequences must include at least one element, or else the
optimal solution would have already been found by the recursive call on the opposite side. On the other
hand, we don’t know if k elements are enough on one side without knowing what happens with minSeq-k
elements on the other side. It seems like some searching will be required, and it will increase the worst-case
running time of the algorithm by some factor related to minSeq."

Comment: The tricky case is when considering a (say, left) border with k < minSeq elements in it: in this case, it's not enough to know the largest overall right-border, because it might be too short.  Hint: What you actually want to know in this situation is the largest right-border *that has length at least minSeq-k*.  The question is: How to calculate this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

```js
int maxSumRec( const vector<int> & a, int left, int right, int L )
{
 int center = ( left + right ) / 2;
 ...
 int maxBorderSum = 0, leftBorderSum = 0;
    // for( int i = center; i >= left; i-- )
    // {
        // ...
    // }

    // int maxRightBorderSum = 0, rightBorderSum = 0;
    // for( int j = center + 1; j <= right; j++ )
    // {
        // ...
    // } 
 int partialSum[1000] = {0}, dpR[1000] = {0};
 for(int i = center + 1; i <= right; i++) 
  partialSum[i] += partialSum[i-1];
 for(int i = right; i > center; i--)  
  dpR[i-center] = max(partialSum[i], dpR[i-center+1]);
 
 for(int i = center; i >= left; i--){
  leftBorderSum += a[i];
  int leftLength = center - i + 1;
  int minRightLength = L - leftLength;
  maxBorderSum = max(maxLeftBorderSum, leftBorderSum + dpR[minRightLength]);
 }
  
 ...
 return max3( maxLeftSum, maxRightSum, maxBorderSum);
}
```

My idea is replace the commented part to something like this (kinda pseudo, just to demonstrate the idea)

First, I calculate `partialSum[]` and `dpR[]` , both use `O(n)`

partialSum[i] = sum from a[center] to a[i]

dpR[i] = Maximum sum on the right side of center which at least length i

So now as we got the maximum sum on the right zone of specific length, we can find the border sum which at least of length `L` by doing:

For each left element you pick, say you pick 3 elements, we find dpR[L-3] and sum them up to get the sum, we take the maximum in this process

(Note: the code is for illustrating purpose, you should aware of those minor stuff like you must at least pick 1 element per side; the for loop boundary handling when calculating `partialSum[]` and `dpR[]`, etc)